# Can't capture URL string attributes via RequestParameter()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Am trying to put the this link in a triggered email:

```
<a href="http://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=3935619f7de112efe7216b2b61beb90aceb7e386bfb7bcccdb7c20bb&subkey=%%_subscriberkey%%&demail=%%emailaddr%%&lkey=%%=v(@lkey)=%%&dname=%%=v(@dname)=%%&lemail=%%=v(@lemail)=%%&lstatus=1">Yes status 1 confirmed< /a>
```

This link leads to a landing page, where I am trying to get the passed values.   I can see the values in URL, but I can't access it in the landing page.

In the landing page I use:

```
%%[
 SET @clkey= RequestParameter('lkey')
 SET @csubkey= RequestParameter("subkey")
]%%
<p>yes: %%=v(clkey)=%%</p>
<p>%%=v(csubkey)=%%</p>
```

Also, how can i use MicrositeURL/microsite_base_url instead... to replace email link i used above...to pass parameters with the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't forget to prefix your AMPScript variables with an "@":

```
%%=v(@varname)=%%
```

If you use MicrositeURL() in your email, all of the subscriber attributes will be retrievable using the AttributeValue() function.  In your email 77777 is the PageID of your landing page:

```
<a href="%%=MicrositeURL(77777)=%%">Landing Page URL</a>
```

Then in your landing page:

```
%%[

var @sk
set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

]%%

<p>SubscriberKey: %%=v(@sk)=%%</p>
```

More info:

[MicrositeURL()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#MicrositeURL)

[AttributeValue()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#AttributeValue)

Comment: If i want to add hardcorde value of the attribute like &lstatus=1 or &lstatus=2..I tried below in the email but failed : are they correct ? %%=Concat(MicrositeURL(9703598),'&',"lstatus","3")=%% and %%=MicrositeURL(9703598,"lstatus","3")=%% and get values in LP : set @sk = AttributeValue("lstatus")...%%=v(@sk)=%%

Comment: Query parameters are retrieved with QueryParameter() function in your landing page, not AttributeValue() .  I would try this in your email: %%=concat(micrositeURL(9703598),"&lstatus=3")=%%

Comment: tried but ...HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.   and in the URL http://cl.exct.net/%%=Concat(MicrositeURL(9703598)...

Comment: I'd then just try tacking the parameter on the end:  <a href="%%=MicrositeURL(9703598)=%%&lstatus=3">link</a>

Answer (score 1):

Seconding this answer. Also % (percent) characters in the URL can lead to some crazy behavior. If MicroSiteURL doesn't work for you, I strongly recommend using the Concat function for the URL and add the parameter variables to the end.